# unable to store phone login credentials in mongodb from firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, mongodb-authentication

I am using firebase and mongodb atlas. I have saved social media login credentials like email, name, picture in mongodb users collection. but I am unable to save phone login credentials like phone number and uid. when I login into app using social login, I am getting id like the below image. [image]

but when I login into app using phone number, I am unable to get id. May be the reason the phone credentials was not saved. How can I get id value at the time of phone login. In Mongodb realm app, we store value like this.
[image]

could you please help me with the solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of object are you getting when the phone auth is successful?

Comment: @JuanDavid am getting uid value like this uid: "hmp5BSlfS4d7JleKuhIGIAdf2lJ3"

Comment: Isn't the uid what you are looking for? Could you please clarify what is the issue?

Comment: @JuanDavid when I login with google credentials, i am getting id value in console like the above picture. But when i login with phone number, i am getting uid not id. we need id for save credentials in Realm appuser in mongodb. without id i can't save credentials in mongodb

Comment: I believe that the id you get from Google auth is an internal Auth0 id that Google uses, if you are trying to save firebase credential you should always use the uid that firebase provides every time a succesful auth event occurs. This uis should be present in all forms of firebase authentication because that is how firebase identifies you users. Use that property instead.

Comment: @JuanDavid BUt I am  unable to get uid in social login, i am getting id and we need same id some thing like. I have added one more picture in question of mongodb realm app user for your reference purpose. there, we have stored id value.

Comment: Please see latest answer update

Answer (score 0):

You should use the UID that firebase provides in both cases. All forms of firebase authentication provide this property as this is the way Firebase identifies your users. If you are trying to save the firebase Auth credentials to mongodb, use the UID.

You can find the uid of a social auth provider like this.

```js
firebase.auth()
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
    var credential = result.credential;

    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    const uid = user.uid
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: I am getting uid in both cases and i have stored uid in firebase authentication user. but we need id to store user details in mongodb realm app. without id we can't store the user in mongodb realm app.

Comment: I think the id you are looking for is generated by the federated auth provider (Google, Facebook or whatever). It is possible that Firebase phone auth does not provide this. Why can't you use the uid as the mongodb id?